# Invisible Marker Symbol

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, symbology

I'm attempting to place a custom marker over a point in my ArcMap add in on my map but nothing shows up on the map. What am I doing wrong? The file extracts correctly and I can view it just fine if I open the .emf but the image doesn't appear over my point or even appear at all.

```
    internal static void IndicatePoint(IGeometry shape)
    {
        //Get and clear the graphics layer
        var graphics = ArcMap.Editor.Map.ActiveGraphicsLayer as IGraphicsContainer;
        graphics.Reset();
        graphics.DeleteAllElements();

        if (shape != null)
        {

            //Compose the symbology
            var symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol();

            var extractedPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "SelectionSymbol.emf");

            if (!File.Exists(extractedPath))
            {
                var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), @"ArcGIS\Addins\Desktop10.4", ThisAddIn.AddInID, @"xivictoolbar.esriaddin");
                using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.OpenRead(path))
                {
                    ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = zip.GetEntry(@"Images\SelectionSymbol.emf");
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    using (Stream zipStream = zipEntry.Open())
                    {
                        zipStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    }

                    var bytes = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    memoryStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);

                    File.WriteAllBytes(extractedPath, bytes);
                }
            }

            symbol.CreateMarkerSymbolFromFile(esriIPictureType.esriIPictureEMF, extractedPath);
            symbol.Size = 24;
            symbol.Angle = 0;
            symbol.XOffset = 0;
            symbol.YOffset = 0;
            symbol.Color = new RgbColor() { Red = 255, Green = 255, Blue = 100 };

            //Compose the marker
            var marker = new MarkerElement();
            ((IMarkerElement)marker).Symbol = symbol;
            marker.Geometry = shape;

            //Add marker to map
            graphics.AddElement(marker, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Has the spatial reference of the geometry been set? Try using a simple marker symbol to see if there's something that ArcMap doesn't like about the EMF picture.

Comment: Using a simple marker symbol works fine.

Comment: Can you create a marker symbol from the EMF manually? Can you try a simpler format (like .BMP or .TIF) to build the marker symbol? I'm thinking that ArcMap may not like that particular flavor of EMF or possibly the extraction isn't 100% complete by the time you try to load the picture; although ArcObjects is single threaded Windows is not and the bytes may just be 'on the way' to the file when the process continues... try putting a thread.sleep https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx for a few miliseconds (50 or so) to give the extraction a chance.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the extraction, it's just that arcmap doesn't like my EMF. At least that's what ESRI support told me. They said that my EMF has this error in it: "The Image has an unsupported Color Space". If you're having this issue, I'd try googling this error. I on the other hand have just worked around this issue but I'll come back to it at some point and post my solution here when I have one.